# Problem with importing rospy and roslib libraries

Tags: python, ros

I am new to ROS and python. This question could be silly but spent almost 5 hours on this. I am using PyCharm (Latest version) with Python 2.7.15 64 bit (Also tried with 3.x). I need to import a few libraries as below:

```
import roslib;
roslib.load_manifest('smach_tutorials')
import rospy
import smach
import smach_ros
```

However, PyCharm fails to identify roslib, rospy, smach and smach_ros (could not find in the interpreter also to import). The above libraries are example given in the official site:

http://wiki.ros.org/smach/Tutorials/Simple%20State%20Machine

OS: Windows 7 (64 bit)

ROS not installed: (*"SMACH is a ROS-independent Python library to build hierarchical state machines"* - from the official site)

Error Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/****/Desktop/Python/TestCharm.py", line 3, in <module>
import roslib;
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'roslib'
```

Comment: What is your installed ROS version? `manifest` file is available on ROS Fuerte and earlier.

Comment: ROS not installed. I hope it is not mandatory to install ROS (Please correct me if I am wrong)

Comment: Please put on your full traceback error on your question

Comment: Where is your reference to smach without using ROS? I couldn't find any thing, However, if smach is ROS-independent, you need only to import Smach and remove the ROS library and dependencies from your code.

Comment: I am still confused... 
"Smach, which stands for "State Machine", is a powerful and scalable Python-based library for hierarchical state machines. The Smach library does not depend on ROS, and can be used in any Python project" - This is from the website. But I also see that they use roslib and rospy in the example. I have updated my question with error traceback.

Comment: I said in the previous comment that if Smach is ROS-independent, you must remove ROS libraries from your code (only `import smach` remains)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the support. I found out it is not possible for my perticular case to use SMACH because it has dependency on catkin. I am using Windows 7 and should be upgraded to windows 10 or use Ununtu Linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the catkin version of ROS (Groovy and later), it does not use the `manifest` file but uses the `package.xml` file instead.

So your code will be:

```
import rospy
import smach
```

---

Apparently, your code is ready for ROS Fuerte or earlier version.

---

With supposing that Smach is ROS-independent, you need only to the `import smach`

Comment: ROS not installed. Is it mandatory to install it? I saw that smach library is independent of ROS

Comment: I'll check it, I used that by installed ROS before.

Comment: Please let me know if you have installed ROS on Windows. Because as I see roslib is only available for python 2.7(32 bit) for Windows. 64-bit package require business edition license. Also ROS windows installation guide says Windows 10 is the requirement. I have Windows 7.

Comment: `roslib` is an old version of ROS library, also `rospy` is a ROS library, so with supposing that  Smach is ROS-independent you need only to the `import smach`